# Jenkins pass environment variables as parameters

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, devops, gatling, jenkins-groovy

I am preparing the performance testing scripts(gatling) for our internal applications.This performance testings scripts execute on many Jenkins agents(~ 7 jenkins agents).

I would like to pass my all application/gatling related environment variables as Jenkins parameters to the Jenkins pipeline.Then application/gatling can read the environment variable and execute the performance testing base on the environment variables which is provided as Jenkins parameter

My code :

```
pipeline {
agent { node { label 'performance-test-agents-1' } }

    parameters {
    string(defaultValue: "https://rems-xxxxxxxxxx.dev-xxx-xxx.xx.xx.local", description: "please provide the base url for target environment", name: "Baseurl")
    string(defaultValue: "10", description: "set the execution duration", name: "duration")
    string(defaultValue: "20", description: "set the qps value for throttling", name: "maxqps")
    string(defaultValue: "10", description: "set the initial concurrent users", name: "initUsers")
    string(defaultValue: "20", description: "set the ramping user count", name: "rampUsers")
    booleanParam(defaultValue: false, description: 'Update pipeline parameters without building/deploying', name: 'update_params_only')
    }

    environment {
      DURATION   = "${duration}"
      MAXQPS     = "${maxqps}"
      INITUSERS  = "${initUsers}"
      RAMPUSERS  = "${rampUsers}"
      DIRECT_LOGGINGAPI_URL = "${Baseurl}"
      ONLY_UPDATE_PARAM = "${update_params_only}"
   }
```

The error I am getting :

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "null"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:766)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.StringGroovyMethods.toInteger(StringGroovyMethods.java:3312)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$1160.doMethodInvoke(Unknown Source)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1213)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:42)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:163)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:23)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:107)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:161)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:165)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:39)
at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:86)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:113)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(FunctionCallBlock.java:78)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor541.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:129)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:268)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:51)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:185)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:400)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$400(CpsThreadGroup.java:96)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:312)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:276)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:67)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Finished: FAILURE

Comment: you need to enclose the parameters like below in declarative pipeline.
DURATION   = "${params.duration}"
MAXQPS     = "${params.maxqps}"

Or you can directly use "${params.duration}" any where in your jenkinsfile.

Comment: To add to @vijay's answer, you may want to manually copy params into environment with e.g. `for (param in params) {env[param.key] = param.value}`. Remember that boolean params (`true`, `false`) will convert to strings (`"true"`, `"false"`).

Comment: @MaratC Both of you are wrong. Jenkins makes parameters automatically available as regular Groovy variables and as environment variables. The code sample works but it is missing the part that is actually failing: "at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:39)"

Comment: Can you post the part of the code where it is failing? Your parameters and environment blocks are fine.

Comment: Hi Vijay , MaratC Thanks for reply, the answer fixed my issue

Hi @zett42 Thanks for replying.  could you please elaborate the comment. sorry I am new to Jenkins pipeline

Comment: You did not post the whole pipeline script. Stack trace shows that the script failed at line 39. Please include this part too.